# Can RxJava2 CompositeDisposable Clean Itself of Disposed Subscriptions?

Tags: rx-java2

From time to time me App triggers a `Single` for a network request, which I add to a `CompositeDisposable` in case I need to cancel all pending network requests.

The `CompositeDisposable` will add a `Disposable` to a inner `HashSet`, so with time the more `Single`s I add, the more memory the `CompositeDisposable` will take.

Are there any ways for the `CompositeDisposable` to make a "clean up", removing all `disposed` `Disposabled` from its inner `HashSet` saving up memory?

Comment: This is not supported. You have to remember each disposable and remove them manually. The easiest way is to use `DisposableSingleSubscriber` and `subscribeWith` so that the `onSuccess` and `onError` implementation can simply call `remove(this)`.

Comment: Is it a lot of work to add a method on `CompositeDisposible` to iterate into the `HashSet` and removed already `disposed` subscriptions, like a `cleanDisposed()`?

Comment: We'd rather not call an arbitrary `isDisposed` while holding a lock, however, It would be possible to add a `getDisposables` that returns a list of all known disposables. At this point though, you may be also inclined to implement a custom `CompositeDisposable` container for yourself.

Comment: I think a `getDisposables` is good enough, it can be iterated even without a lock, worst case just some very few subscriptions will have disposed and we won't see them as disposed, but still can clean up all the others that for sure are already disposed, something like a "best effort to clean without slowing down the code"

Comment: May I open a feature request for `CompositeDispodable` subscribe to the `complete` and `error` of the added Observable and remove it automatically?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. There is an extension feature [subscribeAutoDispose](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#subscribeautorelease) that can do this.

Comment: I meant to add a feature to `CompositeDisposible` so it can auto remove disposed subscriptions, the same way `DisposableSingleSubscriber` does. I want to keep my app small and not add an additional library, since android apps don't deal well with app size.

Comment: I suggest you copy `CompositeDisposable` by source into your project and make the modifications that you are comfortable with.

Comment: Ok, I will, if it works I will send it to you guys to review, so if you want you can integrate it into the library

Comment: The API of `CompositeDisposable` is fairly unchanging at this point so there is no need to contribute back your changes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I'm not sure if it's the best approach, but I implemented it in this way:

```
package io.reactivex.disposables

import io.reactivex.internal.util.OpenHashSet

fun CompositeDisposable.clearDisposed() {
    if (disposed) {
        return
    }
    var notDisposedSet: OpenHashSet<Disposable>
    synchronized(this) {
        if (disposed) {
            return
        }
        notDisposedSet = OpenHashSet()
        for (res in resources?.keys().orEmpty()) {
            if (res is Disposable && !res.isDisposed) {
                notDisposedSet.add(res)
            }
        }
        resources = notDisposedSet
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution in Kotlin was to create such an extension function:

```
fun <T> CompositeDisposable.subscribeAndPush(single: Single<T>,
                                             onError: ((t: Throwable) -> Unit)? = null,
                                             onSuccess: (t: T) -> Unit) {

    lateinit var disposable: Disposable

    disposable = single.doAfterTerminate {
        this.remove(disposable)
    }
    .subscribe(onSuccess, onError ?: {})

    this.add(disposable)

}
```

Then sample usage:

```
compositeDisposable.subscribeAndPush(
            authenticationRepository.login(credentials), ::onError) { result ->
           
           // on success here

}
```

Actual subscription is being done in extension, so before that, there is a place for another listener allowing composite to remove disposable. Don't know if it's a good solution but maybe it will help someone.